# Resume a stopped build process with Apache Ant

Tags: java, ant, build, build-process, kettle

Yesterday I had to stop Ant build process of [Pentaho-kettle](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle) which was taking so long; and today it starts all the processes (tests, packaging, ..) from the beginning. Is there any way that I can resume the building process from the point it was stopped? Tests also **could not** be skipped with the option:

`ant dist -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

and I didn't find out how to tell ant, **not to build the packages if they already exist**.

Comment: Just try it and u will know. But better do not mess and just make something ant clean and then ant dist. Building process takes like couple of minutes. It is not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you completely a successful build on your machine? You have not indicated which steps are taking a long time.

I notice that the project is using [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage its dependencies. The first time a build runs will be the longest since the dependencies must be first downloaded and cached. Subsequent builds should run faster.

As for the setting the "maven.test.skip" that only applies to Maven based builds. Maven is a different build tool.